# BST validity checker | posted multiple times on chegg and they've gotten it wrong too

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

## 11.19 LAB: BST validity checker

## Step 1: Inspect the Node.java file

Inspect the class declaration for a BST node in Node.java. Access Node.java by clicking on the orange arrow next to LabProgram.java at the top of the coding window. Each node has a key, a left child reference, and a right child reference.

## Step 2: Implement the BSTChecker.checkBSTValidity() method

Implement the checkBSTValidity() method in the BSTChecker class in the BSTChecker.java file. The method takes the tree's root node as a parameter and returns the node that violates BST requirements, or `null` if the tree is a valid BST.

A violating node will be one of three things:

- A node in the left subtree of an ancestor with a lesser key
- A node in the right subtree of an ancestor with a greater key
- A node with the `left` or `right` field referencing an ancestor

Note: Other types of BST violations can occur, but are not covered in this lab.

The given code in LabProgram.java reads and parses input, and builds the tree for you. Nodes are presented in the form `(key, leftChild, rightChild)`, where leftChild and rightChild can be nested nodes or "None". A leaf node is of the form `(key)`. After parsing tree input, the BSTChecker.checkBSTValidity() method is called and the returned node's key, or "No violation", is printed.

Ex:

If the input is:

```
(50, (25, None, (60)), (75))
```

which corresponds to the tree above, then the output is:

```
60
```

because 60 violates BST requirements by being in the left subtree of 50.

If the input is:

```
(20, (10), (30, (29), (31)))
```

which corresponds to the tree above, then the output is:

```
No violation
```

because all BST requirements are met.

The input format doesn't allow creating a tree with a node's child referencing an ancestor, so unit tests are used to test such cases.

my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BSTChecker {
    public static Node checkBSTValidity(Node rootNode) {
        return checkBSTValidity(rootNode, null, null);
    }
    
    private static Node checkBSTValidity(Node node, Node min, Node max) {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }
    
    // Check if the current node violates BST requirements
    if ((min != null && node.key <= min.key) || (max != null && node.key >= max.key)) {
        return node;
    }
    
    // check left + right subtrees
    Node leftViolation = checkBSTValidity(node.left, min, node);
    Node rightViolation = checkBSTValidity(node.right, node, max);
    
    // Return violating node if found
        if (leftViolation != null)
        return leftViolation;

        else if (rightViolation != null)
        return rightViolation;

        else
        return null;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: the errors come from Invalid tree with right child linking to ancestor, Invalid tree with left child linking to parent, and Invalid tree with left child linking to ancestor.

Comment: There is no question here. What are you asking?

Comment: You have to verify that the binary tree provided to you is valid

Comment: That is not a question.

Comment: How is it "not a question" I am asking HOW DO I VERIFY A BST. My code is wrong and I dont know what is wrong with it. SO I AM ASKING WHAT IS WRONG WITH MY CODE

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see that in your post. It just presents a code challenge and ends with a block of code. Only the title says something about "wrong", but it is about chegg. It really doesn't tell us that something is going wrong in your code, let be that it tells for what input it produces wrong output, and what you have done to debug the situation. Anyhow, this question is a duplicate. See banner at the top.

Comment: I just used your answer and I got a 10/10 thank you so much but I don't understand why we need to use a hashset could you please elaborate?

Comment: The  hashset serves to detect that there is a cycle in the graph. It collects nodes on the path down. If then a child happens to be the same node that was already encountered on the way down, there is a cycle.

Comment: Thank you, but why are we "backtracking" with this line of code --> ancestors.remove(rootNode);  

what purpose does it have?

Comment: That is when you move out of recursion and that node is no longer on the path (the path becomes shorter when getting out of recursion -- its like moving one level up in the tree).